# Problems with Gmail account: Error 93

Tags: gmail

I'm trying to login to my Gmail account but I keep getting an error message number code 93.

How can I fix this and access my account?

Comment: _Where_ are you seeing this issue? Can you provide a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen of past occurrences of this issue, this is most likely just a temporary issue in one of Google's data centers. Once they fix it, the issue should clear up on its own.

You can, of course, check the [App Status Dashboard](http://www.google.com/appsstatus) to see if there are any known outages being tracked. Most likely, though, it's probably localized to just a handful of accounts.